# AWS CLI, List ECR image which I specify with tags

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli, aws-ecr

Lets say "foo" is the repository name and I want to call the image which has two tags "boo, boo-0011"

This command displays all the images in the repository:

aws ecr describe-images --repository-name foo --query "sort_by(imageDetails,& imagePushedAt)[ * ].imageTags[ * ]"

From this how do I grep only the one which has a tag "boo"

Answer (score 3):

You can use `--filter tagStatus=xxx` but that only allows you to filter on TAGGED or UNTAGGED images, not images with a specific tag.

To find images with a specific tag, say `boo`, you should be able to use the somewhat inscrutable, but very helpful, [jq](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) utility. For example:

```
aws ecr describe-images \
    --region us-east-1 \
    --repository-name foo \
    --filter tagStatus=TAGGED \
    | jq -c '.imageDetails[] | select( .imageTags[] | contains("boo") )'
```

Comment: I one wanted to just select the imageTags attribute using jq, how would  we do that?

Comment: @mike01010 if you're asking how to restrict the output to just the tags then append `| .imageTags` to the jq query. Other usage examples [here](https://www.baeldung.com/linux/jq-command-json) and the jq playground [here](https://www.devtoolsdaily.com/jq_playground/).

Answer (score 1):

Personally I use grep for this

```
aws ecr describe-images --repository-name foo --query "sort_by(imageDetails,& imagePushedAt)[ * ].imageTags[ * ]" | grep -w 'boo'
```

-w is the grep command for the whole word matching.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a pure jmespath query which will find the image which contains your tag.  It filters all the images to find those with a tag containing your string, then selects the elements you need from those images.

```
--query 'imageDetails[?imageTags[?contains(@,`boo`)]].[imagePushedAt,imageDigest,imageTags]'
```

Warnings:

This will also select "boo-far" and "farboo".
If you want to use a variable for your search, change the quoting style:

```
--query "imageDetails[?imageTags[?contains(@,\`${tag}\`)]].[imagePushedAt,imageDigest,imageTags]"
```